# Pass variable to datasource for kendo dropdowntree

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-dropdown

I was trying to implement Kendodropdowntree , I came across following situation which I am not able to understand

```
        
                $(dropdowntree).kendoDropDownTree({
                placeholder: "Select ...",
                height: "auto",
                dataSource:  //HARD CODED VALUE GOES HERE 
            });
       }
```

Above example will work fine when , I hard code those datasource values.
When I try to pass some variable there it will not work

```
var datatobind= somedata // data in exact format it is expected 
{
        
                $(dropdowntree).kendoDropDownTree({
                placeholder: "Select ...",
                height: "auto",
                dataSource:  datatobind
            });
       }
```

Even I tried passing variable of following type

```
var dataSourcetype = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: datatobind
    });

 
{
        
                $(dropdowntree).kendoDropDownTree({
                placeholder: "Select ...",
                height: "auto",
                dataSource:  dataSourcetype.options.data
            });
       }
```

But even above also doesn't solve problem, I am not able to get it , why passing exact same variable is not
binding to data source.

Comment: try to add  the properties dataTextField and dataValueField with the corresponding values on your data

Comment: even when properties are there it will not work

Comment: any console errors? Is it possible so see the data structure? That would help

Comment: no any console error

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this?

The datasource variable:

```
var dataToBind = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "url/to/your/data",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            hasChildren: "HasChildren" //boolean value
        }
    }
});
```

Then your kendoDropDownTree should look like this:

```
$("#dropdowntree").kendoDropDownTree({
        dataSource: dataToBind,
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        placeholder: "Select ...",
        height: "auto"
    });
```

Note that the id in the datasource variable has to match the one in the dataValueField on the kendoDropDownTree